# Factory without inject the dependency

Tags: angularjs

This is my code that currently works:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('myCtrl', function (DocumentTypeManagerPdf, DocumentTypeManagerVideo) {

    $scope.showPreview = function(document){
      var previewModule = eval('DocumentTypeManager' + document.clientModule);
      previewModule.show(document);
    };

  });
```

but... two things I would avoid:

1. Eval is evil
2. I am forced to inject every DocumentTypeManagerXYZ that I'll implement

In there a better solution tu use a Factory dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `arguments` in the function. inJS every function has a variable named arguments which is a array of given parameters.

But I am not sure how your `DocumentTypeManagerXYZ` objects are structured. So just type `debugger;` beginning of your controller function and check `arguments` data by console then you can take a correct action.

the below one is the first one comes to my mind;

```
var previewModule;
for(var i = 0, len=arguments.lengh; i <len; i++) {
   if (arguments[i].constructure.name === 'DocumentTypeManager' + document.clientModule) {
      previewModule = arguments[i];
      break;
   }
}
```

this will be your basic approach.
as this is an angular application you can user `$injector.get("moduleName")`

for example;

```
var previewModule = $injector.get("'DocumentTypeManager' + document.clientModule");
```

please see [$injector](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should go with a factory pattern.

One service DocumentTypeManagerFactory

With one method like

```
var myDocumentTypeManager = DocumentTypeManagerFactory.instanciateWithType(document.clientModule);

myDocumentTypeManager.show(document);
```

Your controller will only inject one service (and the DocumentTypeManagerFactory should inject all)

In your DocumentTypeManagerFactory you should make a switch or if/else to avoid eval.